# Increase padding of div based on screen size

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

I have just started media queries and flex and I have not that knowledge about CSS.

I have a divB that is inside a container divA. I want to make this responsive, such that if the screen size is getting less than a certain point then divB size will get shrink at the same proportion. And if the screen size is getting larger, at certain point divB size will be fixed and the padding of container divA will be increased as the screen grows. How can I do that using media queries and flex?

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/w0fopsyp/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-element">
  </div>
</div>
```

but I am little confused how to do that?

Please ignore if question is too basic to ask?

Comment: vmax or vmin units might do : forked : https://jsfiddle.net/w0fopsyp/3/   tutorial about https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: Thanks!! vmax is working for padding but I want to fix the size of internal div at certain screen size so only padding will be increased

Answer (score 1):

as per the screen size you can change responsive media query the "padding:20px"

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container{
      border:2px red solid;
      padding:20px
    }

    .table-element{
      border:2px green solid;
      height:50px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1166px) {
        .container{ padding:50px;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
        .container{ padding:50px;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:980px) {
        .container{ padding:50px;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:767px) {
        .container{ padding:50px;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:599px) {
        .container{ padding:50px;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:479px) {
        .container{ padding:50px;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:374px) {
    .container{ padding:50px;}
    }
    </style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-element">
  </div>
</div>
```